# php: replace url by link unless its a picture tag

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, image, detect

I use a script which detects a url in a string and replaces it with an anchor tag:

```
$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$mytext);
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>",$string);
```

It works fine, unless it encounters an image tag. For instance:

```
<img src="http://www.xx.com/img.jpg" alt=""/>
```

will become:

```
<img src="<a href="http://www.xx.com/img.jpg">http://www.xx.com/img.jpg</a>http://www.xx.com/img.jpg" alt=""/>
```

How should I modify this preg_replace in order not to alter the url if ' **src="** ' comes just before it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right before the `/` at the end of each regex:

```
(?<!\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))
```

This should check to ensure the last bit (the extension part) is not one of the standard image formats.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kolink. So just before the "/i" right? Tried it and generated an error message. But it wouldn't help that much as what you suggest focuses on the file extension, not on the img tag which means that a url to a picture file would never be a url. What I need is just to ignore image tags and if an isolated url is a file url, let's make a link out of it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: "a url to a picture file would never be a link"